# lua cjson cannot decode specific unicode char?

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, lua, torch

I'm getting the following error from lua cjson when trying to decode a specific unicode char,

```
root@9dc8433e6d83:~/torch-rnn# th train.lua -input_h5 data/aud.h5 -input_json data/aud.json -batch_size 50 -seq_length 100 -rnn_size 256 -max_epochs 50
Running with CUDA on GPU 0  
/root/torch/install/bin/luajit: train.lua:77: Expected value but found invalid unicode escape code at character 350873
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'read_json'
    train.lua:77: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'dofile'
    /root/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/trepl/scm-1/bin/th:145: in main chunk
    [C]: at 0x00406670
```

by following the source, I can see that train.lua read_json is using cjson under the covers.

The unicode escape code in question is \uda85

If I go to https://www.branah.com/unicode-converter  it tells me the character the escape should decode to.

The unicode escape was generated using python unichr(55941) and written to a file with PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8 via redirection of the python script output.

The following demonstrates how the character was generated;

```
echo "print unichr(55941)" > test.py
python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    print unichr(55941)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\uda85' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

# export PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8
# python test.py
���
# python test.py > tfile
# cat tfile
���
# python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> f=open("tfile",'r')
>>> s=f.readline()
>>> s
'\xed\xaa\x85\n'
>>> print s
���

>>> s.decode('utf-8')
u'\uda85\n'
```

What I am trying to do overall is take a set of integers in the range 0-65535 and using python map them to UTF-8 chars and write them out to a file. Then I would like to use torch-rnn that uses LUA to train an RNN on the sequence of chars. I'm getting the error when attempting to run th train.lua on the files generated by the torch-rnn python scripts/preprocess.py

Comment: `\uda85` is first code of surrogate pair, there must be second code (dc00-dfff) following the first code to complete the unicode character.  The first part without the second is an error.

Comment: Ah interesting, thankyou. Do you know of a list showing just all the surrogate pairs? in this application, I can simply switch them to a different value without issues, so I can hardcode a check for them.  - also,  just out of interest, how is the decoding site I linked to generating a valid character when I only give it \uda85 to decode?

Comment: @MattWarren Leading or "high surrogates" range is D800–DBFF, and trailing or "low surrogates" range is DC00–DFFF. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Character_Set_characters#Surrogates

Comment: thanks, I'd been poking around but hadn't found that page. Now I can hack 'em out :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems the problem was unicode surrogates, understanding that means I can filter/switch them for different values. In this use case, thats not such a big problem.